# configure ngrok as service > permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, service, permissions, ngrok

I have a permissions error while attempting to setup ngrok as a service.

```
$ sudo ngrok service install --config /home/m/snap/ngrok/79/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml


INFO[08-12|19:11:50] open config file                         path=/home/m/snap/ngrok/79/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml err="open /home/m/snap/ngrok/79/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml: permission denied"
INFO[08-12|19:11:50] detect init system                       sys=linux-systemd
CRIT[08-12|19:11:50] install failed                           err="Failed to install ngrok: open /etc/systemd/system/ngrok.service: permission denied"
```

Installed ngrok on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS using snap.

```
sudo snap install ngrok
```

```
which ngrok
/snap/bin/ngrok

ngrok config check
Valid configuration file at /home/m/snap/ngrok/79/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml
```

current permissions.

```
user@blah:~/f_projs/ngrok_config$ ls -la /snap/bin/ngrok
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Aug  4 16:53 /snap/bin/ngrok -> /usr/bin/snap
user@blah:~/f_projs/ngrok_config$ ls -la /home/user/snap/ngrok/79/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml
-rw------- 1 m m 167 Aug 12 19:01 /home/user/snap/ngrok/79/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a trivial permissions problem, having checked the permissions, I'm confused.

Comment: ngrok is owned by root and has permissions lrwxrwxrwx. Directory /etc/systemd/system/ is owned by root and root has rwx permissions on this folder. the ngrok.yml file is owned by user m and has permissions -rw-------, reading ngrok.yml is not the problem.  still don't understand why I'm experiencing 'permission denied' error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 20 / ngrok installed via snap.
Like you I couldn't figure out what happens with permissions.
Solved it by reinstalling ngrok via apt (see https://ngrok.com/download).